# Facebook web app: How to store an ID for user recognition

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-javascript-sdk

My company is developing a web app, we are looking to integrate this to Facebook, basically our web app provide some reports. Now some of the clients want to show some information in Facebook. Even though, we dont have any experience developing for Facebook we opened a developer account and we selected build a web-app(We are thinking to embed our web-app in Facebook).

So our question is:

- how we could store an ID of our client once he install the app in Facebook?
- does Facebook store this ID and every time a visitor in our client's Facebook app enters to the app in Facebook, Facebook sends this ID to our website to recognize which client is it?

Thanks for any inside on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad. I would advise to start reading the documentation on [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login) to get an idea about how it works.

In general, when an user logs in using Facebook, you will receive an *App Scoped User ID*. That is an ID that is unique and identifies the user for your app (note: for the same user, each app gets a different ASUID). You can use this ID to keep track of all your users.